# How to debug code executed at application's startup if application is hosted in IIS and starts when IIS does?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I have a .NET application which is server framework and it is hosted in IIS and it starts when IIS does.

To debug the framework I attach to the client process by Visual Studio. It works for normal debugging, but now I want to debug section when framework loads its configuration from xml files (it is handled by C# code). It does it only once when application starts so exactly the same time the IIS starts. I am not faster than IIS with attaching my solution.

If I attach framework to the client process then reset the IIS the debugger will be detached.

How to handle such problem?

Bad solution: The only way may work is to put a very long Thread.Sleep at the beginning of the app and then attach quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the IIS"? Does the debugger detach if you just recycle the application pool?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes. If you go to IIS GUI on the upper right corner you'll have RESTART button.

Comment: That is different than recycling the app pool.

Comment: I tried it, it still detaches the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

to `Application_Start`. You'll get a popup asking you if you want to debug the website, and if you click OK, you'll be taken to Visual Studio in debug mode, paused at that line.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your project to using "IIS Express" instead of Local IIS - when you then start the app, Visual Studio will start the IIS Express as well, with the debugger already attached to the service.

You can change the setting by right clicking on the project => choose Properties => click the Web tab => find IIS Express in the combobox under "Servers".

Comment: Ok cool, do you know how I can select which IIS I want to use(I'll have access to the machine with the code and tools tomorrow) but I thought that maybe that is some standard trick. Also the client app runs on the same IIS that Framework does.

Comment: In my original comment I wrote how to configure the server to use IIS Express. When you do this, it will reveal the new url for the server (will most likely be localhost and a random port number, like this: http://localhost:1236 - you just point your client to this url and it should work, assuming it's on the same machine)

Comment: @Yoda, what about this issue? Could you get useful information from lmms90's suggestion?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Unfortunately not, tried that didn't help. It is probably a valid solution when dealing with smaller solutions. I just had to understand the code.